# Git will not remove untracked files

Tags: git

I pulled from our staging today and discovered that code pushed by someone else earlier is broken. So I did `git reset --hard <previous commit>`. This does nothing.

I can `git reset` to any fool thing I want, all the merged changes are still present in my local copy. So I have been reading through every permutation of resetting a pull I can, trying to `reset`, `revert`, `clean`, whatever, but regardless of the approach I take I cannot get the pull reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Run `git log` and pick the hash of the last commit that works for you; then give `git reset --hard $HASH` and your local copy will be reverted.

If it does not work, please provide the commands that you have performed, with their respective output.

Comment: So here it is: 
git reset --hard e6b16e9  
HEAD is now at e6b16e9 MOB-4247 Updated some images for ******  

Looks great. Except then you do a git status and you get  

our branch is behind 'origin/staging' by 21 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)  
#  
# ../actionbarsherlock/  
# ../adb  
# ../core-library/res/drawable-  hdpi/btn_check_off_disabled_focused_holo_light.png  
# ../core-library/res/drawable-  hdpi/btn_check_off_disabled_holo_  
etc.

Comment: Those files can be cleaned with `git clean -fx`. If you need to remove those faulty commits from the history, you might need either `git revert` (if you want to remove just some commits), or directly `git push origin staging -f`, if you want to **wipe them out completely, forever**.

Comment: Don't force push unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to go back one commit you can do `git checkout HEAD^`

If you want to go back to an old commit.

1. git log
2. Find out the
3. do a git checkout HASH
   OR
   git checkout -b state HASH